# In the R shiny package, how to stop the side and main panels from overlapping the title panel?

Tags: r, shiny

When running the below code and viewing in the window, the side panel ("Modeled periods") and main panel ("Table of input range") overlap and cover the title panel ("Vector generator"). How do I shift the side and main panels down, in order to uncover the title panel?

You can also view this strange output in the image at the bottom.

Please note that the scrolling works correctly: the title panel and left-side panel remain fixed, while the main panel on the right (with its very long data table output) scrolls.

The below code is boiled down to a working minimum from the full version, in order to isolate the problem at hand when running it:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(   
  
  tags$style(type='text/css', 'body { overflow-y: scroll; }'), 
  
  titlePanel(actionButton("explain1",
                          strong("Vector Generator"),
                          icon = icon("info-circle"),
                          style="color: #fff;background-color: #337ab7;font-size:19px;
                                 border-color: #2e6da4;width: 75vw;
                                 position:fixed;")
  ), # closes title panel
  
  sidebarLayout(
     sidebarPanel(
       actionButton("explain2","Modeled periods",icon = icon("info-circle"),
                    style = "text-align:center;width: 35vw"),
       
       style = "position:fixed;
                width = 75vw",
       
       sliderInput("periods", "",min = 1, max = 120, value = 60),
     ), # closes sidebar panel
    
    mainPanel(
      width=6,align="center",h5(strong("Table of input range")),
      tableOutput("view1")
    ) # closes main panel
  
  )   # closes sidebar layout
)     # closes user input (UI) section

server <- function(input, output, session) {   
  
  periods <- reactive(input$periods)
  
  output$view1 <- renderTable(seq(1:periods()),rownames = FALSE)
  
  observeEvent(input$explain1,
               {showModal(modalDialog(title = "Vector generator","Pending..."))})
  observeEvent(input$explain2,
               {showModal(modalDialog(title = "Modeled periods","Pending..."))})
  
} # closes user server section

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Output image:[image]

Comment: One solution would be to move the `actionButton` out of the `titlePanel` and into the `sidebarPanel`, but do you necessarily need the button to be in the `titlePanel`? The titlePanel generally just contains a text title

Answer (score 0):

Changing fixed by relative in position appears to be working.

```
titlePanel(actionButton("explain1",
                        strong("Vector Generator"),
                        icon = icon("info-circle"),
                        style="color: #fff;background-color: #337ab7;font-size:19px;
                             border-color: #2e6da4;width: 75vw;
                             position:relative;")
```

Comment: "Position: relative" does eliminate the overlap issue, but it also nullifies maintaining the title panel as a fixed header while scrolling down. I'm trying to maintain the title panel as a fixed header while scrolling down.